# How to alter HTTP Response header categorization in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

In Fiddler, when I get an HTTP response, in the Headers tab (it's the Standard.ResponeHeaderView inspector), the response headers have been automatically 'categorized' so that, for instance, some are identified as 'Cache' headers, some as 'Entity' and so forth. Is there any way to alter this categorization?

For instance, I would like to identify some headers as coming from e.g. Akamai, based on the header name, so that I can click on the header to compress them from the view, if I don't care about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Inspector is not [presently](https://fiddler.ideas.aha.io/) customizable in that way. You could write FiddlerScript to remove unwanted headers from the responses entirely, or you could write your own Inspector that hides the headers of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Eric. :( Still a frowny-face because I can't change it without writing a new Inspector, but it's certainly not your fault :)